# How to insert an image using draft.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

Here is my code trying to insert an image in the draft.js editor. But I failed. When I clicked on the button, only several empty lines were inserted, what's the problem?

**MyEditor.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Editor, EditorState, AtomicBlockUtils} from 'draft-js';

export class MyEditor extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Insert an image</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const base64 = "data:image/png;base64,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";
    const newEditorState = this.insertImage(this.state.editorState, base64);
    this.onChange(newEditorState);
  };

  insertImage = (editorState, base64) => {
    const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
      'image',
      'IMMUTABLE',
      { src: base64 },
    );
    const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    const newEditorState = EditorState.set(
      editorState,
      { currentContent: contentStateWithEntity },
    );
    return AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(newEditorState, entityKey, ' ');
  };

}
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyEditor/>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For image support you should use a draft-js image plugin such as draft-js-image-plugin: https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/image

By default draft-js doesn't support plugins, so it's a good idea to use draft-js-plugins-editor, which extend draft-js functionality.

So your code would be:

```js
import React from "react";
import { convertToRaw, EditorState, AtomicBlockUtils } from "draft-js";

import Editor from "draft-js-plugins-editor";
import createImagePlugin from "draft-js-image-plugin";

const imagePlugin = createImagePlugin();
const plugins = [imagePlugin];

export default class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
    this.onChange = editorState => this.setState({ editorState });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor
          editorState={this.state.editorState}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          plugins={plugins}
          ref={element => {
            this.editor = element;
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Insert an image</button>
        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(
            convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()),
            null,
            "  "
          )}
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const base64 =
      "data:image/png;base64,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";
    const newEditorState = this.insertImage(this.state.editorState, base64);
    this.onChange(newEditorState);
  };

  insertImage = (editorState, base64) => {
    const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
      "image",
      "IMMUTABLE",
      { src: base64 }
    );
    const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    const newEditorState = EditorState.set(editorState, {
      currentContent: contentStateWithEntity
    });
    return AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(newEditorState, entityKey, " ");
  };
}
```

The latest versions of draft-js-image-plugin has an error, so you can use 2.0.1 version.

I'm using the latest draft-js version `"draft-js": "0.10.5",`, `"draft-js-image-plugin": "2.0.1",` and `"draft-js-plugins-editor": "2.0.3",`

Comment: Thanks, it really worked! But could you tell me why it didn't work without this plugin?

Comment: Draft-js has limited blocks by default. 
 However you can add custom block support to your draft-js by passing blockRendererFn to draft-js (you can see more information here https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-components.html), but it's easier to do  with draft-js-plugins-editor, where this function is already defined.

Comment: "you can add custom block support to your draft-js by passing blockRendererFn": Doc link changed, see 
https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-components
https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-custom-block-render-map

Answer (score 1):

You can add images without plugins, see [official demo called "Media"](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/v0.11.7/examples/draft-0-10-0/media/media.html)

It uses [blockRendererFn](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-components) attribute of draft-js `Editor` component.

```
const Image = (props) => {
  return <img src={props.src} style={styles.media} />;
};

const Media = (props) => {
  const entity = props.contentState.getEntity(
    props.block.getEntityAt(0)
  );
  const {src} = entity.getData();
  const type = entity.getType();

  let media;
  if (type === 'image') {
    media = <Image src={src} />;
  }

  return media;
};

function mediaBlockRenderer(block) {
  if (block.getType() === 'atomic') {
    return {
      component: Media,
      editable: false,
    };
  }

  return null;
}

// . . . . .
<Editor
   blockRendererFn={mediaBlockRenderer}
```

Comment: i was trying this but when i paste some image all i get is this  "", the block type is unstyled

Answer (score 1):

As of **2021**

**draftjs v 0.11.2**  integrated with **react-draft-wysiwyg 1.14.7**.

I was able to add an image doing the following.

```
const addImage = () => {

    // CREATE <img /> block
    const entityKey = editorState // from STATE
      .getCurrentContent()
      .createEntity('IMAGE', 'MUTABLE', {
        src:'some_img_url',
        height: '100px',
        width: '100px',
    }).getLastCreatedEntityKey();
     
    // NEW EDITOR STATE
    const newEditorState = AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(
      editorState,
      entityKey,
      ' '
    );

    // SETSTATE
    setEditorState(newEditorState);
}
```

Comment: Only thing that has worked for me so far!  Anyone know of a way for the editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText() to track the url for the backend to see the image url?   I can track via another useState as a workaround, but wondering if there is a way to see it from the editorState.  Right now it's just empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addImage` function in the `imagePlugin`

```
// import `Editor` from `'@draft-js-plugins/editor` and not `draftjs`
import Editor from '@draft-js-plugins/editor';
// call create plugin
const imagePlugin = createImagePlugin();
// you can find `addImage` function inside the created `imagePlugin`
const { addImage } = imagePlugin;
const image = "https://.....";
// create editorState
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() => EditorState.createEmpty());
// inside your insert image function
const insertImage(){
  const newState = addImage(editorState, image);
  // setEditorState(newState);  does not seems to work all time, use settimeout
  setTimeout(setEditorState, 0, newState);
}

// add imagePlugin to the list of plugins
<Editor
   editorState={editorState}
   onChange={setEditorState}
   plugins={[imagePlugin, /* Other plugins here*/]}/>
```